# Creating new records in PL/SQL scripts

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have got two tables in my database. I want to check a condition in Table1. If it becomes true then I have to generate two records in Table2.
I am using OracleSQLDeveloper and I want to write a PL/SQL script for it. What is the best way in which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

After you take a tutorial and try to learn the basis of PL/SQL, then it should look something like this:

```
declare
  v_indicator varchar2(100) := '';
begin
  -- read indicator from Table1
  select some_colmn into v_indicator 
    from Table1 
   where some_criterium='some_value' 
  ;
  -- check indicator value against some of your condition
  if v_indicator = 'condition_matched' then
    -- log information to server output
    dbms_output.put_line('condition_matched');
    -- generate records:
    insert into Table2 (col_t2) values ('r1');
    insert into Table2 (col_t2) values ('r2');
  else
    -- here it means condition was not matched
    dbms_output.put_line('condition NOT matched');
  end if;
end;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. But I have to insert values from table1 in some of the table2 columns. I don't want to hardcode it. How to do that in insert statement?

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in PL/SQL, as proposed by J. Chomel, is readable and good. But you can do it in pure SQL too, if that is necessary for some reason:

```
insert into table2(col_t2)
   select val from (select 'r1' val from 
                    dual union all 
                    select 'r2' from dual)
     where exists (select 'x' from table1
                     where some_criterium='some_value')
```

Obviously, something like that is no very readable.